# What is the difference between HTML and 'rendered HTML' when rendering a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, server-side-rendering

As seen in numerous articles about webpage rendering. What is the difference between the two?

Another example: ("Once the request is done processing, your browser gets back the fully rendered HTML and displays it on the screen.") [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-exactly-is-client-side-rendering-and-hows-it-different-from-server-side-rendering-bd5c786b340d/]

Another example: ("Server-side rendering (SSR) is an application’s ability to convert HTML files on the server into a fully rendered HTML page for the client.") [https://www.omnisci.com/technical-glossary/server-side-rendering]

Bonus points for anyone who can give examples of actual differences in the code.

Comment: at a guess, without ANY context (a link to just one of the numerous articles would give context) HTML is text ... rendered HTML is what you see on your browser

Comment: Short version: HTML is a markup language used to create web documents. Rendered HTML is the HTML created by a JavaScript framework like React or Angular by translating JS code into the HTML that browsers understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common term when working with Single Page Applications (SPAs) built on React, Angular, Vue, etc. These frameworks render out Typescript/Javascript into browser-readable HTML. This is different then just making a raw .html file because these framework scripts are being 'rendered' as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, HTML is a markup language that can be used to make web pages. Content wise, rendered or not, it will have the same tags `<html></html>`, `<body></body>`, and so on.

The only different I see as a user is that for a static HTML page, the id tags (e.g. `<div id="myID"></div>`) and class tags will likely be same for each visit.

However for rendered HTML page, the ids and classes might be different each time. (e.g. `<div id="myID12"></div>` for 1st time, but `<div id="myID34"></div>` for the second).

One possible incentive for using rendered HTML is to prevent other people from using web crawlers or automated programs on the website. I hope this answers your question.